# MAC id eth0 and wlan0 for flexlm servers

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, ifconfig

I am trying to set up a flexlm server. The vendor asked me to send the MAC ID of my system. I typed ifconfig. And found that there are 2 different HWaddress for eth0 and wlan0. Which one is the MAC id my system? The vendor has already generated license file for wlan0 hardware address. I tried making wlan and eth0 HW address same by using

ifconfig eth0 hw ether ADDRESSS

However, the server still had some issue.
Could someone tell me which is the MAC ID of my server?

Comment: ask the vendor, he sure must know

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is a good idea to set the MAC address of two devices on the same machine to be the same. It may even work if the devices are on separate networks, but still - it's at least confusing.

Your server has two network interfaces, so it has two MAC addresses.
Technically, there is no difference between wlan and eth regarding being a network interface.

The reason that the software ignores wlan and only looks at eth when checking the license could be a convention.
Practically, every server has an eth interface, which is possibly unused, of course. And it can have multiple eth interfaces.
So it would make some sense that the MAC of `eth0` is used - but they forgot to tell you the implicit convention.

It would not be a very clean solution, but you could try to set the MAC of `eth0` to the licensed MAC, as you did, but change the MAC of `wlan0` to something else.

The above is independent of flexlm, as I do not know that software;
But I found some specific information about the issue here:

[Post "FlexLM has 2 physical addresses shown in Hostid. Is this a problem?
" in the Autodesk forum.](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/installation-licensing/flexlm-has-2-physical-addresses-shown-in-hostid-is-this-a/td-p/3454690)

It states that the license is checked against the MAC addresses of all network interfaces on the server, so that part should work.

The described solution is something like disabling IPV6, plus a change in the `/etc/hosts`.